# slicing a 3D image data set at different angles

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working with a 3d stack of CT data. I'm interested to define a plane and slice this 3D image dataset with this plane. I'm using MATLAB to do this. I have attempted a few different approaches, including rotating the image data set prior to slicing it, however, imrotate() only rotates the image in one direction (about the z-axis I believe).

I have also tried defining the plane and intersecting it with each image slice and defining the data points by interpolation. I thought and still think this is a clean way of approaching the problem, however I have not succeeded in finding out why the approach is not working. I understand that my image is defined as coordinates, while when I try to define the plane MATLAB does this through dimensions. As straightforward as it sounds I have been struggling with figuring out the solution for a while now.

I appreciate any help guiding me to a solution.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using ITK (http://www.itk.org/Doxygen41/html/annotated.html) for working on medical images. MATLAB is not very helpful when working with large medical images. There are varuous filters in ITK which cna solve your purpose, e.g., ExtractSliceImageFIlter... May be a simple cropping is what you want... Its bit of a pain to learn ITK initially but totally worth it... refer the ITK Documentation and examples... all the doubts that you have about using any function etc can be understood by looking at solved examples give...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! However, I have to use MATLAB, the image is not very large and this is for a project that I'm working on. I have heard of ITK and someone else has also recommended looking into it for general medical image processing. Nonetheless, given the other parts of my project I have to work with MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/image/3d_mri/tform3.html

i hope this help,
 i would also go with magarwal suggestion , matlab people are  usually taking ITK filters  and implementing it in Matlab,
so if you have C++, java, python , c# or any skill of the above you can use itk .
and Trust me you will be ahead than Matlab while waiting for them to implement filters they already have in ITK