# Extract 2D slice from a 3D volume in a certain angle

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D Volume (x,y,z-matrix) and want to extract 2D slices from the volume.
The problem is that the orientation of the 2D-slices varies: The slice has a random angle in the 3D volume which means that I need to interpolate the pixelvalues in the 3D volume accordingly.

Is there an easy way to realise this in Matlab?

Thanks!

Comment: What about [slice](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html)? Have you had a look at [interp3](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html)? Also there's this similar question: [slicing image data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377428/slicing-a-3d-image-data-set-at-different-angles?rq=1)

Comment: Yet [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426112/matlab-saving-a-slice-through-volumetric-data-to-an-image), and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083351/extract-arbitrarily-rotated-plane-of-data-from-3d-array-as-2d-array).

Comment: What did solve your problem? If one of the other questions was exactly what you wanted let's mark your question as a duplicate, so in the future people can refer to the other one. If it was something else please consider writing an answer to this question, so we can give something back to the community.